# SQL product many catgeorys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL server 2012 and office 365 excel;
I have the following example data in a table:

Sample:

```
pd_code, height, width, length, pd_catdesc, Category
derp   , 1     , 1    , 1     , derp desc , cattop>>catmain>>catsub___18
```

the total rows when i select from my table is 10976,  if i take out category and group by all other columns i get 10691 (correct unique parts).

**Reason**

A product can have more than 1 category. The issue I face is for an import.
A product has a category defined like...

> category___18;

If I want to add multi i need to simply add a semi colon

> category___18; category___20;

From the data as you can see my category field is actually the tree, i have some excel code that rids me of all but the sub category. Excel code

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CR3,">>",REPT(" ",250)),250))
```

> category___18;

**What I need**

what I need to do to the data is to filter out those multi category products. so I can do a bulk import of single category products.

then I need to do a new query that somehow will take all the sub categorys for a product and create a string like

> category___18;category___20;

**Summary**

So I need to only return unique rows based on pd_code but contain a column that will display a subcategory like

> cat___18;

And any other categorys like

> cat___18;cat___19;

**Further Clarification**

I need an SQL query that will produce a new column called "categoryrefined" for example, this query needs to look to see if 2 rows are identical (except for category field) then combine category into the new column as explained. (please note the trim method in excel example provided)

**Even more clarification and data for a specific user:**

The following data is a quick select * from statment that filters 1 pd_code (product) from the table.

```
|pd_code | Height | width | length |  pd_catDesc                             | category     
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------     
| TC TSPM|     67 |  3000 |     76 | Traditional Cornice Pumice Plain Shaker | Kitchens >> Front Matching Features >> Front Matching Features >> Traditional Cornice___1959 |     
| TC TSPM|     67 |  3000 |     76 | Traditional Cornice Pumice Plain Shaker | Kitchens >> Front Matching Features >> Front Matching Features >> Traditional Cornice___1967 |     
| TC TSPM|     67 |  3000 |     76 | Traditional Cornice Pumice Plain Shaker | Kitchens >> Front Matching Features >> Front Matching Features >> Traditional Cornice___1968 |
```

So as you can see above 3 rows same code different categorys.  I need to make this into one row like

```
| TC TSPM|     67 |  3000 |     76 | Traditional Cornice Pumice Plain Shaker | Cornice___1959;Cornice___1967;Cornice___1968;
```

At this point im not sure how much more i can clarify this question any further.  If you require additional information I will try and provide.

Comment: Check this answer maybe some of those is what you are looking for. **A)** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns  **B)** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: use `control-K` to format table as code

Comment: So you want `GROUP BY pd_code` and concatenate the last category?

Comment: Pretty much yes, only quirk is (excel reference) my category field contains the full Hierachy, i need to trim the result first then concat the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attempt Trim Part:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/VEZ55708)**

```
SELECT [pd_code], [Height], [width], [length], [pd_catDesc],
       REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(category), charIndex(' >>', reverse(category)) -1 )) as [category]
FROM PRODUCT;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

WITH GROUP_CONCAT:

```
WITH trim_cat as (
    SELECT [pd_code], [Height], [width], [length], [pd_catDesc],
           REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(category), charIndex(' >>', reverse(category)) -1 )) as [category]
    FROM PRODUCT
)
SELECT DISTINCT
      [pd_code], [Height], [width], [length], [pd_catDesc],
      [category] = (
          SELECT tc.[category] + ' ; '
          FROM trim_cat tc
          WHERE tc.[pd_code] = t.[pd_code]          
          FOR XML PATH('')          
          )
FROM trim_cat t
```

[image]

Comment: just checked the results yes that seems to do the same as the excel example nice one.  Yes next process would be to group the results and concat the dup results with the trimmed categorys seperated by semi colon

Comment: Excellent just tried it and seems to be exactly what i need, many thanks for that!  do you mind if we delete the page of crappy comments ?

Comment: Check again, I forget include the `DISTINCT`

Comment: Distinct throws "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Comment: I try to sort by category, but couldnt, but because that wasnt a requirement I just remove the sort.  If that is a requirement, will need to do more research.

Comment: No worrys, sort is not a req, thanks for the help on this.

Comment: if you need it just change it to `ORDER BY [category] FOR XML PATH('')          `